# Dynamic columns with BIRT, changing colspan

Tags: report, birt

I have a row that uses an expression like this:

```
if (row["type"] == "OTHER") {
dataSetRow["questionText"]
}
else {
dataSetRow["exposure"]
}
```

I want it so that when the "type" is "OTHER" that it will change the colspan to 4, thus ignoring the other columns.  But in other cases it will be the normal colspan of 1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

In your report, select the cell that you want to modified.
Then go to `script` tab, select `onRender` script.
I've tried this code using eclipse IDE and it's work properly.

```
this.colSpan=3;
```

So modify that code as you want.

More about BIRT cell element : [Cell](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/ref/rom/elements/Cell.html)

Comment: I only want this on certain rows.  Is that still allowed?

Comment: thanks, it's working in preview mode.  Unfortunately when I run it, the other cells are blank but are over top of the cell.  If I select the text I see that it goes under those blank cells.  I tried setting their colspan to 0 and that almost works but the grid lines are still there.